# Slider with arrows

Tags: jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm creating a slider which runs alongside the orbit slider from zurb. The point in this is that I want to control two slideshows with one set of nav arrows... Here's what I'm adding to the orbit.next function:

```
$('.description > p:visible')
  .fadeOut(500)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(500)
  .end()
  .appendTo('.description');
```

That is the code for the next arrow but how can I adapt this code so it works on the previous arrow as well?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know about orbit slider, but i thought i can help somehow, here's what i got to so far

```
$('.description p:last-fo-type')
  .fadeOut(500)
  .prev()
  .fadeIn(500)
  .end()
  .prependTo('.description');
```

If i misunderstood anything, please let me know. So i can do the necessary corrections.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I hav figured it out...

```
  this.$element.bind('orbit.next', function () {
    self.shift('next');

    if ($('.description > p:visible').is(':not(:last-of-type)')) {
      $('.description > p:visible').fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn(500);
    } else {
      $('.description > p:visible').fadeOut(500);
      $('.description > p:first').fadeIn(500);
    }
  });

  this.$element.bind('orbit.prev', function () {
    self.shift('prev');
    if ($('.description > p:visible').is(':not(:first-of-type)')) {
      $('.description > p:visible').fadeOut(500).prev().fadeIn(500);
    } else {
      $('.description > p:visible').fadeOut(500);
      $('.description > p:last').fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
```